# Save image in database visual studios

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, image, byte

i would like to know how to save an image into database. I know that we have to convert the image into a byte first and then save it in the database. I have set the data type to byte in the database. I need example projects or code samples on how to go about doing this in visual studios 2010 C#.
Thank You

Comment: Instead of saving bytes in the DB , you should put the images in server and save the image url to the database.

Comment: yes, however due to certain limitations.. i wont be doing that.. I will be saving the image into the database.

Answer (score 1):

if you want find your image

```
        FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(yourPath);
        long numBytes = fInfo.Length;
        FileStream fStream = new FileStream(sPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fStream);
        byte[] imageData = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);
```

try with these lines based on object type

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Image", (object)imageData));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey You can save image on a location on your server and save just the name of image in database.